# Setting a font directly vs using FontFamily

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Assume b to be an instance of the Button class. Is there any difference when we directly create a font as in:  `b.Font = New Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)`

Versus

when we create a font family first and then create a font from that, for example:

```
Dim fontF As New FontFamily("Arial")
b.Font = New Font(fontF, 15, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
```

I have a feeling that there is no difference between these two and that there is no extra advantage if we use the FontFamily class. Am I Right? In other words, are there situations where using FontFamily class helps us?

Comment: There really isn’t any difference,  compiler will shorten it to the first method, but really comes down to personal style

Comment: There's no advantage. In the Constructor of the second form, the `fontF.FontFamily` is copied over and the Font is initialized as in the first form and a new Font is generated. So you should dispose of `fontF` after `b.Font` is assigned. -- You use the second form if you already have a Font and you need to change some of its styles (or any other property value).